# Compare Cell value with Max in that group getting error SELECT Failed 3707

Tags: sql, max, case, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I was trying to compare the cell value with the max value in that group from a view but it is throwing me an error.

The Inner query is working fine it gives me a list of the patient, their indications and count of 2017 and 3yr claims. In the outer query, I need to keep only patient and only that indications along which 2017 claims >0 and has max claims in 3yrs.

It is here where the code is throwing the error

```
SELECT patient_id, 
       CASE 
         WHEN Count(patient_id) = 1 THEN diagnosis_grouping 
         WHEN claim_2017 > 0 
              AND claims_3yr = Max(claims_3yr) THEN diagnosis_grouping 
         ELSE NULL 
       END AS INDICATION 
FROM   (SELECT patient_id, 
               diagnosis_grouping, 
               Sum (CASE 
                      WHEN LEFT(service_date, 4) = '2017' THEN 1 
                      ELSE 0 
                    END)                       AS CLAIM_2017, 
               Count(DISTINCT claim_id)        AS CLAIMS_3YR, 
               Max(Cast(service_date AS DATE)) AS LATEST_CLAIM 
        FROM   l01_dx_claims A 
               INNER JOIN diagnosis_code_imm B 
                       ON A.diagnosis_code = B.diagnosis_code 
        GROUP  BY 1, 
                  2 
        HAVING Count (DISTINCT claim_id) > 1 
               AND Sum(CASE 
                         WHEN Cast(LEFT(service_date, 4) AS INT) = 2017 THEN 1 
                         ELSE 0 
                       END) > 0 
        ORDER  BY Cast(patient_id AS INT), 
                  diagnosis_grouping) 
GROUP  BY patient_id
```

Comment: Remove the `order by` and add an alias for the Derived Table. What data type is `service_date` date or string? Can you show some example data and expected result?

Comment: Thanks Simonare

The order by is there so that I can check the values. Correct me if I am wrong but an Alisa name works with order by as well.

Comment: The service_date is of Varchar datatype  and of the format YYYY-MM-DD

The expected result is two column Prescriber ID and  Diagnosis grouping column that satisfies the given result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider multiple CTEs for the two levels of aggregations:

```
WITH agg1 AS
       (SELECT patient_id, 
               diagnosis_grouping, 
               Sum (CASE 
                      WHEN LEFT(service_date, 4) = '2017' 
                      THEN 1 
                      ELSE 0 
                    END)                       AS CLAIM_2017, 
               Count(DISTINCT claim_id)        AS CLAIMS_3YR, 
               Max(Cast(service_date AS DATE)) AS LATEST_CLAIM 
        FROM   l01_dx_claims A 
               INNER JOIN diagnosis_code_imm B 
                       ON A.diagnosis_code = B.diagnosis_code 
        GROUP  BY 1, 
                  2 
        HAVING Count (DISTINCT claim_id) > 1 
               AND Sum(CASE 
                         WHEN Cast(LEFT(service_date, 4) AS INT) = 2017
                         THEN 1 
                         ELSE 0 
                       END) > 0
      ),
    agg2 AS 
      (SELECT patient_id,
              COUNT(patient_id) AS patient_count,
              MAX(CLAIMS_3YR) AS max_claims_3yr
       FROM agg1
       GROUP BY patient_id)

SELECT a1.*
FROM agg1 a1
INNER JOIN agg2 a2
  ON a1.patient_id = a2.patient_id
  AND a1.CLAIMS_3YR = a2.max_claims_3yr
ORDER BY CAST(a1.patient_id AS INT),
         a1.diagnosis_grouping
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem occurs here:

```
WHEN Count(patient_id) = 1 THEN diagnosis_grouping 
     WHEN claim_2017 > 0 
          AND claims_3yr = Max(claims_3yr) THEN diagnosis_grouping 
     ELSE NULL
```

Count(patent_id) is aggregate where as claim_2017 is not.

so your group by statement is inefficient for this query. you either need to include claim_2017 to your group by or find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to compare different levels of aggregation, this is how I understand your logic:

```
SELECT patient_id, 
       diagnosis_grouping, 
       Sum (CASE 
              WHEN Left(service_date, 4) = '2017' THEN 1 
              ELSE 0 
            END)                       AS CLAIM_2017, 
       Count(DISTINCT claim_id)        AS CLAIMS_3YR, 
       Max(Cast(service_date AS DATE)) AS LATEST_CLAIM 
FROM   l01_dx_claims A 
       INNER JOIN diagnosis_code_imm B 
               ON A.diagnosis_code = B.diagnosis_code 
GROUP  BY 1, 
          2 
HAVING -- Teradata allows using a Select alias in any place, simplified conditions
       CLAIMS_3YR > 1
   AND CLAIM_2017 > 0
QUALIFY -- using Windowed Aggregates to filter the correct result
        Count(*) -- only a single diagnosis_grouping
        Over (PARTITION BY patient_id) = 1
   OR (      -- there was a claim in 2017
        Max(claim_2017)
        Over (PARTITION BY patient_id) > 0
        AND  -- diagnosis_grouping with the higthest count 
        Row_Number()
        Over(PARTITION BY patient_id
             ORDER BY claims_3yr DESC ) = 1
      )
```